# IE bug asp:textbox after delete and tab changes the input display to absolute 0,0

Tags: asp.net, css, textbox

So I have the weirdest bug, I have a form with several asp:textbox controls if I write the code and make a tab nothing happens everything stays normal but if for any reason I delete some of the text and then change control, the textbox background moves to the upper left corner of the screen, while the text I entered stays on the same place... I'm trying to fix it making the cell that contains the textbox position: relative but now the displays goes over the text and doesn't let me see what I wrote.

Here is my code:

```
<table id="tabla-form1">
    <tr>
        <td class="tabla-form1-cell">
            <span style="float: left;">Nombre</span>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="validNombre" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNombre" ErrorMessage="Necesitas ingresar un nombre" Text="*" ForeColor="Red" />
            <asp:TextBox id="txtNombre" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tabla-form1-cell">
            <span style="float: left;">Apellido</span>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="validApellido" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtApellido" ErrorMessage="Necesitas ingresar un apellido" Text="*" ForeColor="Red" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtApellido" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" />
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="tabla-form1-cell">
            <span style="float: left;">Fecha de nacimiento</span>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="validNac" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNac" ErrorMessage="Necesitas ingresar una fecha" Text="*" ForeColor="Red" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNac" runat="server" CssClass="fecha" /> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is my CSS:

```
input[type='text'] {
    width: 160px;
    height: 20px;
    border-color: #bdbdbd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    color: #454545;
    z-index: 10;
    behavior: url("js/PIE.htc");
}
```

This happens to me both with textboxes with validation and without it, and it only happens in IE, firefox and chrome make it work just fine.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: I think this may be caused by your use of PIE.htc. You note that it's IE only if I understood you correctly (I guess the comma between IE and Firefox / Chrome indicates that in FF and Chrome you do not encounter any problems). Review your PIE.htc js file...

Comment: Hi You're right I removed the pie and it stoped happening - Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As adaam said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139651/ie-bug-asptextbox-after-delete-and-tab-changes-the-input-display-to-absolute-0#comment24805969_17139651), in your CSS, you have:

```
behavior: url("js/PIE.htc");
```

You should review or remove the link to `PIE.htc`.

More information on Progressive Internet Explorer (PIE):

- [Documentation on PIE](http://css3pie.com/documentation)
- [Getting started with PIE](http://css3pie.com/documentation/getting-started/)